# Filter and status parameter does not work on customer/{id}/orders endpoint

Tags: android, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce Rest api to access data in android application.

I am trying to get list of customer's order based on status: pending/processing/on-hold.

for this i used status parameter in query but it does not work. It returns all orders including completed orders.

here is the query:

```
http://192.168.1.105:8081/storeapp/wc-api/v3/customers/13/orders?oauth_consumer_key=ck_e87a74423bc0d77b84446079fabf1fca5e2e1a52&oauth_nonce=1234&oauth_signature=V5L5H0hTSKieItFyl9wmgK4q0Ps%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1443904623&oauth_version=1.0&status=pending
```

It returns all orders i just need orders with pending status (or whatever i specify).

i have tried applying filter parameters for limiting the returned result but that too doesn't work (Works on other endpoints eg. http://192.168.1.105:8081/storeapp/wc-api/v3/orders

I don't want to retrieve all orders and then filter on the client. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the results on the server before it gets sent to the client. You need to use `woocommerce_api_customer_orders_response` filter and filter your orders

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_customer_orders_response', 'custom_response' );

function custom_response( $orders ) {
    // user can pass multiple values separated by comma "," for status parameter
    $order_status = array();

    if( isset( $_GET['status'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['status'] ) ) {
        // getting status values from parameter
        $order_status = explode(",",$_GET['status']);
    } else {
        // no status has been specified return all orders
        return $orders;
    }

    $filtered_orders = array();

    foreach( $orders as $order ) {
        // checking order status against the values received in query
        if(in_array($order['status'],$order_status ))
            array_push( $filtered_orders, $order );     
    }

    return $filtered_orders;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried your solution but it should work.. but i want to get the order with status specified in the query.. how can i get that value in this function?

Comment: You can use `$_GET['status']`  and then compare `$order['status]` against it. Have edited my answer, test it out. Its not tested so may need polishing.

Comment: You answer worked.. suggested an edit which will accept multiple values for status parameter.. for eg. status=pending,processing.. by this we can get orders with status as pending or processing..

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the arrow next to it, so that future visitors know that it works.

Comment: It solves the current problem for retrieving customer's order based on status. but it does not work with filter and other parameters like limit (guess this is not implemented in the api) ....  so should I create a separate / custom endpoint or filter records in this function?  

retrieving all the record and filtering in this call back will effect response time?

Comment: The current code doesn't have filtering or limiting records, so you'll have to create a custom end point if you want to implement them. Retrieving all records and filtering them in the callback might be a bit slower compared to filtering and limiting in the SQL query. Unless you have thousands of records per customer, the response time will be negligible. I don't have a benchmark to support what I said, but you can try and weigh the options out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. as long as there are limited number of records filtering on callback will work.... 

thanks for the help.